# Ingress Nginx - how to serve assets to application

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-config, nginx-ingress

I have an issue, I am deploying an application on [hostname]/product/console, but the .css .js files are being requested from [hostname]/product/static, hence they are not being loaded and I get 404.

I have tried `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target:` to no avail.

I also tried using: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/location-snippet: |
                 location = /product/console/ {
                   proxy_pass http://[hostname]/product/static/;
                 }`

But the latter does not seem to be picked up by the nginx controller at all. This is my ingress.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-resource
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-rewrite-log: "true"
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/location-snippet: |
      location = /product/console/ {
        proxy_pass http://[hostname]/product/static/;
        }
spec:
  rules:
    - host: {{.Values.HOSTNAME}}
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /product/console
          backend:
            serviceName: product-svc
            servicePort: prod ##25022
        - path: /product/
          backend:
            serviceName: product-svc
            servicePort: prod #25022
```

--
Can I ask for some pointers? I have been trying to google this out and tried some different variations, but I seem to be doing something wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to run your application outside of Kubernetes? Does it work there? Have you tried to use a basic solution like `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"` with no other annotations and a basic path like: `"path: /*"`?

Comment: Hey @DawidKruk thanks! I tried that, but still the same. What seems to be the issue is that when I go with public dns `dns/product/console/` the assets are at `dns/product/static`. The requested URL seems to be `IP Address:80`. I wanted to add the proxy pass, but does not seem to work for me. I wonder if it is related to specific version, I am also on GKE.

Comment: As I see from your configuration, the `/product/console` and `/product/static/your_files` are in the same service (hence pod). This should not create any issue when `rewrite-target` is not present, no additional configuration were done on `nginx-ingress` and path is set on `/*` assuming it works outside Kubernetes. I didn't hear you tried it outside of Kubernetes. Could you clarify it? I made a simple example with `index.html` and some `css`. I could post it for a reference but I am not sure this will help with this exact issue you are having.

Comment: @DawidKruk Hey, yes I did try to run it just locally and it works just fine. The exception is that when I run it on localhost, I am using localhost:port instead of public dns. I think rewriting the application so the static assets are configurable is probably the way. But if you have an example that might help, I will appreciate it nonetheless. Cheers

Comment: The thing that using `HOSTNAME/` and `localhost:port` in that case should not make a difference if you do not have any things like `nginx` rewriting your requests on localhost. Basing on your configuration of `Ingress` can you confirm what are you trying to achieve is: 1) when requesting /product pass request to /product 2) when requesting /product/console pass request to /product/static. I will post my example with some troubleshooting steps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR**

To diagnose the reason why you get error 404 you can check in `nginx-ingress` controller pod logs. You can do it with below command:

`kubectl logs -n ingress-nginx INGRESS_NGINX_CONTROLLER_POD_NAME`

You should get output similar to this (depending on your use case):

```sh
CLIENT_IP - - [12/May/2020:11:06:56 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 238 "-" "REDACTED" 430 0.003 [default-ubuntu-service-ubuntu-port] [] 10.48.0.13:8080 276 0.003 200 
CLIENT_IP - - [12/May/2020:11:06:56  +0000] "GET /assets/styles/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "http://SERVER_IP/" "REDACTED" 348 0.002 [default-ubuntu-service-ubuntu-port] [] 10.48.0.13:8080 22 0.002 200
```

With above logs you can check if the requests are handled properly by `nginx-ingress` controller and where they are sent.

Also you can check the [Kubernetes.github.io: ingress-nginx: Ingress-path-matching](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/). It's a document describing how `Ingress` matches paths with regular expressions.

---

You can experiment with `Ingress`, by following below example:

- Deploy `nginx-ingress` controller
- Create a `pod` and a `service`
- Run example application
- Create an `Ingress` resource
- Test
- Rewrite example

#### Deploy `nginx-ingress` controller

You can deploy your `nginx-ingress` controller by following official documentation:

[Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress-nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/)

#### Create a `pod` and a `service`

Below is an example definition of a pod and a service attached to it which will be used for testing purposes:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ubuntu-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ubuntu
  replicas: 1 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ubuntu
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ubuntu
        image: ubuntu
        command:
        - sleep
        - "infinity" 
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ubuntu-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: ubuntu
  ports:
    - name: ubuntu-port
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 30080
  type: NodePort
```

#### Example page

I created a basic `index.html` with one `css` to simulate the request process. You need to create this files inside of a pod (manually or copy them to pod).

The file tree looks like this:

- **index.html**
- assets/styles/**style.css**

**index.html**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hi</h1>
</body>
```

Please take a specific look on a line:

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/style.css">
```

**style.css**:

```css
h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

You can run above page with `python`:

- `$ apt update && apt install -y python3`
- `$ python3 -m http.server 8080` where the `index.html` and `assets` folder is stored.

### Create an `Ingress` resource

Below is an example `Ingress` resource configured to use `nginx-ingress` controller:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-example
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: 
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: ubuntu-service 
          servicePort: ubuntu-port
```

After applying above resource you can start to test.

#### Test

You can go to your browser and enter the external IP address associated with your `Ingress` resource.

**As I said above you can check the logs of `nginx-ingress` controller pod to check how your controller is handling request.**

If you run command mentioned earlier `python3 -m http.server 8080` you will get logs too:

```sh
$ python3 -m http.server 8080
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8080 (http://0.0.0.0:8080/) ...
10.48.0.16 - - [12/May/2020 11:06:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10.48.0.16 - - [12/May/2020 11:06:56] "GET /assets/styles/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

#### Rewrite example

I've edited the `Ingress` resource to show you an example of a path rewrite:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-example
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: 
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /product/(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: ubuntu-service 
          servicePort: ubuntu-port
```

Changes were made to lines:

```yaml
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
```

and:

```yaml
      - path: /product/(.*)
```

Steps:

- The browser sent: `/product/`
- Controller got `/product/` and had it rewritten to `/`
- Pod got `/` from a controller.

Logs from the`nginx-ingress` controller:

```sh
CLIENT_IP - - [12/May/2020:11:33:23 +0000] "GET /product/ HTTP/1.1" 200 228 "-" "REDACTED" 438 0.002 [default-ubuntu-service-ubuntu-port] [] 10.48.0.13:8080 276 0.001 200 fb0d95e7253335fc82cc84f70348683a
CLIENT_IP - - [12/May/2020:11:33:23 +0000] "GET /product/assets/styles/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "http://SERVER_IP/product/" "REDACTED" 364 0.002 [default-ubuntu-service-ubuntu-port] [] 10.48.0.13:8080 22 0.002 200
```

Logs from the pod:

```sh
10.48.0.16 - - [12/May/2020 11:33:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10.48.0.16 - - [12/May/2020 11:33:23] "GET /assets/styles/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Please let me know if you have any questions in that.

Comment: oh wow, thank you @david.kruk. I will definitely give it a go once I am freed up as I have been allocated elsewhere. I really really appreciate it though! Cheers