# Google Kubernetes Engine ingress annotations

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I configure Ingress on google Kubernetes engine. I am new on ingress but as i understood ingress can serve different Loadbalancers and different LBs should be differently configured.

I have started with a simple ingress config on GKE :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: basic-ingress

spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: web-np
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /v2/keys
        backend:
          serviceName: etcd-np
          servicePort: 2379
```

And it works fine so I have 2 different NodePort services web-np and `etcd-np` . But now I need to extend this logic with some rewrite rules so that request that points to `/service1` - will be redirected to the other `service1-np` service but before `/service1/hello.html` must be replaced to `/hello.html`. That's why I have the following questions:

- How can I configure rewrite in ingress and if it is possible with default load balancer.
- What is default load balancer on GKE.
- Where can I find a list of all annotations to it. I have thought that the full list is on https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/ but there is a completly different list and there is no `kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name` annotation that is widely used in google examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> `Ingress` - API object that manages external access to the services in a cluster, typically HTTP.
>
> Ingress may provide load balancing, SSL termination and name-based virtual hosting.
>
> *[Kubernetes.io: Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)*

Kubernetes can have multiple `Ingress` controllers. This controllers are different from each other. The `Ingress` controllers mentioned by you in this particular question are:

- `Ingress-GCE` - a default `Ingress` resource for `GKE` cluster:

  - [Github.com: Kubernetes: Ingress GCE](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce)
- `Ingress-nginx` - an alternative `Ingress` controller which can be deployed to your `GKE` cluster:

  - [Github.com: Kubernetes: Ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx)

`Ingress` configuration you pasted will use the `Ingress-GCE` controller. If you want to switch to `Ingress-nginx` one, you will need to deploy it and set an annotation like:

- `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"`

---

> How can I configure rewrite in ingress and if it is possible with default load balancer.

There is an ongoing feature request to support rewrites with `Ingress-GCE` here: [Github.com: Ingress-GCE: Rewrite](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/109).

**You can use `Ingress-nginx` to have support for rewrites.** There is an official documentation about deploying it: [Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress-nginx: Deploy](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/)

For more resources about rewrites you can use:

- [Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress nginx: Examples: Rewrite](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/)
- [Stackoverflow.com: Ingress nginx how to serve assests to application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61541812/ingress-nginx-how-to-serve-assets-to-application/61751019#61751019) - this is an answer which shows an example on how to configure a playground for experimenting with rewrites

---

> What is default load balancer on GKE.

If you create an `Ingress` resource with a default `Ingress-GCE` option you will create a [L7 HTTP&HTTPS LoadBalancer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress).

If you create a service of type `LoadBalancer` in `GKE` you will create an [L4 Network Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps#creating_a_service_of_type_loadbalancer)

If you deploy an `Ingress-nginx` controller in `GKE` cluster you will create a L4 Network Loadbalancer pointing to the `Ingress-nginx` controller which after that will route the traffic accordingly to your `Ingress` definition. If you are willing to use `Ingress-nginx` you will need to specify:

- `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"`

in your `Ingress` definition.

Please take a look on this article: [Medium.com: Google Cloud: Kubernetes Nodeport vs Loadbalancer vs Ingress](https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-nodeport-vs-loadbalancer-vs-ingress-when-should-i-use-what-922f010849e0)

---

> Where can I find a list of all annotations to it. I have thought that the full list is on https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/ but there is a completly different list and there is no kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name annotation that is widely used in google examples.

**The link that you provided with annotations is specifically for `Ingress-nginx`. This annotations will not work with `Ingress-GCE`**.

The annotations used in `GCP` examples are specific to `Ingress-GCE`.

You can create a Feature Request for a list of available annotations for `Ingress-GCE` on [Issuetracker.google.com](https://issuetracker.google.com).

Comment: > You can create a Feature Request for a list of available annotations for Ingress-GCE on Issuetracker.google.com.
This means that there are no published annotations with descriptions for default google ingress controller ? it is a really surprice . as i understand it is widely used currently how people use it without any documentation

Comment: To get more information about `Ingress-GCE` annotations you can look at the code in the github repository: [Github.com: Kubernetes: Ingress-GCE: Annotations](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/tree/master/pkg/annotations) or look here: [Godoc.org: K8S: Ingress-GCE: Annotations](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/ingress-gce/pkg/annotations)

Answer (score 6):

Answering an old question, but hopefully it can help someone.

I found the [list of annotations](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/blob/master/pkg/annotations/ingress.go) for `GCP Ingress` in the source code for ingress-gce.