# NGINX Installation and Configuration

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, networking, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm new to Kubernetes and wanted to use the NGINX Ingress Controller for the project I'm currently working on. I read some of the docs and watched some tutorials but I haven't really understood the:

- installation process (should I use Helm, the git repo???)
- how to properly configure the Ingress. For example, the Kubernetes docs say to use a nginx.conf file (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/connecting-frontend-backend/#creating-the-frontend) which is never mentioned in the actual NGINX docs. They say to use ConfigMaps or annotations

Does anybody know of a blog post or tutorial that makes these things clear. Out of everything I've learned so far (both frontend and backend) developing and deploying to a cloud environment has got me lost. I've been stuck on a problem for a week and want to figure out it Ingress can help me.
Thanks!

Comment: Hello, this topic could be quite extensive considering the fact of multiple ways of `nginx-ingress` provisioning, the `Service` usage alongside with it and the support for specific features. Also `nginx.conf` is "hidden" behind the `Ingress` resource definition (exec into the `ingress-nginx-controller` Pod and see for yourself. First of all please tell how your Kubernetes cluster was created? Is it on premise one or a provider-managed like `GKE` or `EKS` or `AKS`. Knowing this information would help to give you more specific solution and give you more baseline idea behind it.

Comment: @DawidKruk Thanks for your help in advance! I wanted to host my cluster locally so I'm using the Docker Desktop Kubernetes plugin, it creates a 1 node cluster on my local machine. I followed the "Installation with Manifests" guide on the NGINX website (https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests/). I looked at the config file from exec'ing into the pod like you said and the proxy_pass looks kind of strange to me. If you tell me what .yaml files to include in the question I'll edit it and include them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering:

> How should I install `nginx-ingress`

There is no one correct way to install `nginx-ingress`. Each way has its own advantages/disadvantages, each Kubernetes cluster could require different treatment (for example: cloud managed Kubernetes and minikube) and you will need to determine which option is best suited for you.

You can choose from running:

- `$ kubectl apply -f ...`,
- `$ helm install ...`,
- `terraform apply ...` (helm provider),
- etc.

---

> How should I properly configure `Ingress`?

Citing the official documentation:

> An API object that manages external access to the services in a cluster, typically HTTP.
>
> -- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Services networking: Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)*

Basically `Ingress` is a resource that tells your `Ingress controller` how it should handle specific `HTTP`/`HTTPS` traffic.

Speaking specifically about the `nginx-ingress`, it's entrypoint that your `HTTP`/`HTTPS` traffic should be sent to is a `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` named: `ingress-nginx-controller` (in a `ingress-nginx` namespace). In Docker with Kubernetes implementation it will bind to the localhost of your machine.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: "nginx"
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx
            port:
              number: 80
```

The modified example from the documentation will tell your `Ingress` controller to pass the traffic with any `Host` and with `path: /` (every `path`) to a service named `nginx` on port `80`.

The above configuration after applying will be reflected by `ingress-nginx` in the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file.

> A side note!
>
> Take a look on how the part of `nginx.conf` looks like when you apply above definition:
>
> ```
>                 location / {
>                        set $namespace      "default";
>                        set $ingress_name   "minimal-ingress";
>                        set $service_name   "nginx";
>                        set $service_port   "80";
>                        set $location_path  "/";
>                        set $global_rate_limit_exceeding n;
> ```

On how your specific `Ingress` manifest should look like you'll need to consult the documentation of the software that you are trying to send your traffic to and [ingress-nginx docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/).

---

Addressing the part:

> how to properly configure the Ingress. For example, the Kubernetes docs say to use a nginx.conf file (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/connecting-frontend-backend/#creating-the-frontend) which is never mentioned in the actual NGINX docs. They say to use ConfigMaps or annotations.

You typically don't modify `nginx.conf` that the `Ingress controller` is using by yourself. You write an `Ingress` manifest and rest is taken by `Ingress controller` and `Kubernetes`. `nginx.conf` in the `Pod` responsible for routing (your `Ingress controller`) will reflect your `Ingress` manifests.

`Configmaps` and `Annotations` can be used to modify/alter the configuration of your `Ingress controller`. With the `Configmap` you can say to enable `gzip2` compression and with annotation you can say to use a specific `rewrite`.

To make things clearer. The guide that is referenced here is a frontend `Pod` with `nginx` installed that passes the request to a `backend`. This example apart from using `nginx` and forwarding traffic is not connected with the actual `Ingress`. It will not acknowledge the `Ingress` resource and will not act accordingly to the manifest you've passed.

> A side note!
>
> Your traffic would be directed in a following manner (simplified):
>
> - `Ingress controller` -> `frontend` -> `backend`

This example **speaking from personal perspective** is more of a guide how to connect `frontend` and `backend` and not about `Ingress`.

---

Additional resources:

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Questions: Ingress nginx how sto serve assets to application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61541812/ingress-nginx-how-to-serve-assets-to-application/61751019#61751019)*
- *[Stackoverflow.com: Questions: How nginx ingress controller backend protocol annotation works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64647258/how-nginx-ingress-controller-back-end-protocol-annotation-works-in-path-based-ro/64662822#64662822)*

The guide that I wrote some time ago should help you with the idea on how you can configure basic `Ingress` (it could be little outdated):

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Questions: How can I access nginx ingress on my local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59255445/how-can-i-access-nginx-ingress-on-my-local/59274163#59274163)*

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the amazing answer! I had some difficulties so I uninstalled and then reinstalled everything, following your answer made the process much clearer and I know understand how the Ingress Controller works and is configured. I'm having some problems with my React app right now but I think that's down to some other misconfiguration with the Docker Image. Before that I didn't really understand how the Ingress controller could "configure itself" suing the Ingress resource. Thanks for being so polite also!

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward process of installing nginx ingress controller (or any other for that matter) would be using `helm`. This would need basic understanding of `helm` and how to work with `helm charts`.

Here's the repo: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/charts/ingress-nginx

Follow the instructions in there - quite straightforward if you use the default values. For the configuration, you can customize the chart too before installing. Look at the Readme to see how to get all the configurable options.

Hope this helps as a starting point.

Comment: I'll make sure to give it a look! I'm getting some 404 Not Found errors in the app so I think I misconfigured something and I'll have to look it over. Either that or I delete and re-apply with helm.

Comment: @Stroboscopio 404 not found error could mean that either you haven't configured `Ingress` resource or the `Host` or `Path` doesn't match.