# Angular, NGINX cannot connect to backend on Kubernetes cluster

Tags: angular, nginx, kubernetes

I'm trying to learn K8. I have a frontend app that is made using angular. I'm serving it behind an NGINX proxy. I also have a backend that has functionalities. There are my files,

**nginx.conf**

```
http {
    upstream gateway {
        server sb-gateway:8081;
    }
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    server {
        listen       80;
        sendfile on;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        location /api/ {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_pass http://gateway;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }
}
```

**user.service.ts**

```
...
return this.http.post('/api/login', {data})
...
```

**ui-service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: sb-ui
  name: sb-ui
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 30000
  selector:
    app: sb-ui
```

The backend service is called `sb-gateway` and I'm trying to route all requests that have `/api/` in them to the backend (as specified in NGINX). But I get this error when i try to hit a route from the frontend/pressing a button.

`POST http://192.168.64.2:30000/api/login 404 (NOT FOUND)`.

I'm trying to run this on minikube. I have SSH'd in the frontend pod and tried to curl the backend service. It works. I just need to figure out how am I supposed to communicated from the frontend service to the backend service on angular.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I recommend using nginx ingress instead of configuring a proxy manually.

Comment: I need to agree with a comment made by jordanm. You should be using an `Ingress nginx` and not a single `Pod` with nginx installed. Have you seen this answer by any chance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66641786/nginx-installation-and-configuration/66691013#66691013?

Answer (score 1):

Posting this answer as a community wiki to give more of a baseline on how you can allow/route the traffic to/in the Kubernetes cluster.

Feel free to expand it.

---

Having in mind following statement:

> I'm trying to learn K8.

Instead of using an `nginx` `Pod` that is acting as a proxy, you should be using `Ingress`.

In short `Ingress` can be described as:

> An API object that manages external access to the services in a cluster, typically HTTP.
>
> Ingress may provide load balancing, SSL termination and name-based virtual hosting.
>
> -- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Services networking: Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)*

Through an `Ingress` object you can tell your `Ingress` controller (which in this example will be `nginx-ingress`) to have a specific configuration that will allow you to route the traffic accordingly.

---

Having as an example following situation:

- You have your application that should receive request on a `/api` path
- You have other applications that should receive all other request (in this example simple `nginx` `Pod`)

Being specific to:

> I'm trying to run this on minikube.

`Minikube` has already built-in `Ingress` addon that can be enabled with a single command (there are some exceptions, please refer to the documentation of specific `--driver`):

- `$ minikube addons enable ingress`

With above command you will spawn `nginx-ingress`.

Creating a setup to show how it could be configured:

- `$ kubectl create deployment hello --image=gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:2.0`
- `$ kubectl expose deployment hello --port=8080 --type=ClusterIP`
- `$ kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx`
- `$ kubectl expose deployment nginx --port=80 --type=ClusterIP`

The `Ingress` resource should look like:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: simple-fanout-example
spec:
  ingressClassName: "nginx"
  rules:
  - host:
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: hello 
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx
            port:
              number: 80
```

What above example of `Ingress` will do:

- Request with `/api`, `/api/`, `/api/xyz`, etc.:

  - route to `hello` `Service` with `hello` `Pod`
- Request with `/`, `/xyz`, `/abc/xyz`, etc.:

  - route to `nginx` `Service` with `nginx` `Pod`

> A side note!
>
> If you need to add some specific configuration to your `Ingress` you can check this documentation:
>
> - *[Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress nginx: User guide: Nginx configuration: Annotations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/)*

You can see from the `hello` `Pod` logs:

```sh
2021/04/09 15:22:07 Server listening on port 8080
2021/04/09 15:50:14 Serving request: /api
2021/04/09 15:50:17 Serving request: /api
2021/04/09 15:50:19 Serving request: /api/asdasd
```

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Services networking: Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)*
- *[Minikube.sigs.k8s.io: Docs: Commands: Addons](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/addons/)*
- *[Stackoverflow.com: Questions: Nginx installation and configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66641786/nginx-installation-and-configuration/66691013#66691013)*