# PhpMyAdmin throws 404 error response in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, phpmyadmin

I have an error trying to deploy the official `phpmyadmin` image locally in Kubernetes cluster. Please look at my `yaml` configs. I haven't any idea what I did wrong. I tried `phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin` image but the 404 error stays. I also viewed configs from other people but it doesn't differ from mine. This is my first experience in Kubernetes so maybe I don't know some development approaches.

[image]

ingress-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /phpmyadmin/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: phpmyadmin-cluster-ip-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

phpmyadmin-cluster-ip-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: phpmyadmin-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: phpmyadmin
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
```

phpmyadmin-deployment.yaml Ip 192.168.64.7 is given by minikube.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: phpmyadmin-deployment
  labels:
    tier: backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: phpmyadmin
      tier: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: phpmyadmin
        tier: backend
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
        - name: phpmyadmin
          image: phpmyadmin:latest
          ports:
            - name: phpmyadmin
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
            - name: PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI
              value: "http://192.168.64.7/phpmyadmin/"
            - name: PMA_VERBOSE
              value: "PhpMyAdmin"
            - name: PMA_HOST
              value: mysql-service
            - name: PMA_PORT
              value: "3306"
            - name: UPLOAD_LIMIT
              value: "268435456"
            - name: PMA_ARBITRARY
              value: "0"
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-secret
                  key: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

I omitted MySQL `yaml` configs thinking it doesn't related to `phpmyadmin` issue but if they can help I will pushlish it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, adding the annotation [`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/) will fix it. How? (*NOTE: I will change service port to `8080` to better distinguish the ports of the `container` and `Service`*).

1. You visit `http://<MINIKUBE IP>/phpmyadmin/` on your browser.
2. The NGINX Ingress controller receives your request, and rewrites the path `/phpmyadmin/` to `/`. The NGINX Ingress controller creates the request to the `Service` in `phpmyadmin-cluster-ip-service` at port `8080` (service port) which has the `targetPort` at `80` (container port) for the pods containing the label `app: phpmyadmin`. One of the matching pods happens to be at `172.17.0.4`:

```
"GET /phpmyadmin/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 22486 "-" ... 492 0.001 [default-phpmyadmin-cluster-ip-service-8080] [] 172.17.0.4:80 22486 0.000 200 ...
```

3. Because the request is now using the correct path for the `phpmyadmin` server, it responds with `200` and the requested resource. We can also see the corresponding logs in phpmyadmin:

```
172.17.0.3 - - [14/Nov/2022:21:58:43 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 22733 "-" ...
```

The IP `172.17.0.3` is of the NGINX Ingress Controller.

There is also a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61541812/ingress-nginx-how-to-serve-assets-to-application) with an even more detailed answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm going to run my application in production and I heard that NodePort is not the best choice for prod. However, I fixed my problem yesterday by changing `$1` to `$2` in `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` annotation. My knowledge in nginx is poor unfortunately, so could you please explain why it worked and should I use it in production?

Comment: NodePort and `kubectl port-forward` are good for testing things out. As for production, you may benefit from either using `Ingress` or a load balancer - e.g., [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/).

I doubt you will use Minikube in production, but cloud providers make it easy for you to deploy your application - for instance, install the Helm chart of the chosen Ingress Controller in the Kubernetes Cluster they provided.

But it depends on whether you really need a Kubernetes Cluster - unless you are building a platform.